# How to fix Necessitas QT Package Error "debug.apk"?

Tags: java, android, c++, qt

I have a problem in building necessitas QT

Packaging Error: Command 'D:/android/QT_again/android-sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe -s emulator-5554 install D:/android/Trial_again/android/bin/QtApplication-debug.apk' failed.Exit code: 1

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to give some more info. The useful part would be in logcat from your emulator. The only thing that is certain is that the package that you are trying to install does not install.